# Simpler way to write 'for' in Octave

Tags: for-loop, matrix, replace, octave

I wrote the following two pieces of code in Octave.

Given a matrix 'img', I wanted to:

Replace all elements that are not equal to 255 with 0:

```
for i = 1:m
    for j = 1:n
        if (img(i,j) ~= 255)
            img(i,j) = 0;
        endif
    endfor
endfor
```

Replace all negative elements with 0 and all elements that are greater than 255 with 255:

```
for i = 1:m
    for j = 1:n
        if (img(i,j) < 0)
            img(i,j) = 0;
        endif
        if (img(i,j) > 255)
            img(i,j) = 255;
        endif
    endfor
endfor
```

Is there a simpler way to write this?

Comment: You could use an else-if in the second for (instead of a separate if) since img(i,j) will either be <0 or > 255 but not both at the same time

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Octave like MATLAB is optimized for matrix or vector calculations. 
That is, it has a lot of optimized compiled code that works very well with things like matrix multiplication or calculating an inverse or adding two matrices, etc.

On the other hand if you make a for loop it cannot take advantage of any of those optimized code and has to be interpreted and so it usually takes much longer to do the same thing.

The style of writing code in the form of vectors (or matrices), or converting to that form  is called "vectorization".

http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Basic-Vectorization.html

For the second case you ask you should try something like this:

```
  img(img<0) = 0;

  img(img>255) = 255;
```

For the first case, something like this:

```
  img(img ~= 255) = 0;
```